# How can I define a static templated variable without knowing the template data type?

Tags: c++, g++

Let's say I have the following struct to store a reference to a class member variable:

```
template <typename  R>
struct Foo {
    R ref;
    int info;
};
class Bar {
public:
    void* run();
};
```

I want to create a const variable of type foo that immediately sets the ref param as follows:

```
const Foo theVar {&Bar::run, 0x1000}; //Doesn't work, but preferred
const Foo<void (Bar::*)()> theVar {&Bar::run, 0x1000}; //Does work, but rather not
```

The reason I'm using a template in this case is because there's no way to cast a class member variable to a `void*`, so I'm forced into this position. However, it seems that I cannot declare the variable without first telling the compiler what type I'm planning to use. Although I do have this information, it's not the prettiest way to accomplish what I want and could possibly cause some issues in the long run.

The compiler should be able to tell that I'm passing a variable of type `void (Bar::*)()` to this struct, so I'm almost certain there has to be a way around this issue.

The reason I'm in need of this struct is because I need a reference to exist for the linker. I don't want it to be set on run-time, it needs to be available for the linker. Using templates seems to be the only way to accomplish this.

Comment: Add a deduction guide: `template<typename R> Foo(R, int) -> Foo<R>;`.

Comment: Since you ask "there's no way to cast a class member variable to a void*" I really wonder what the intent is here. It sounds like trouble. What is the root problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Templates don't really exist unless they're used, so they are, by definition, a compile-time thing.

Comment: Please add the language standard you're using. This does work as-is with C++20. https://godbolt.org/z/jxrKvfv3v

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is simple: add a [deduction guide](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction#Deduction_for_class_templates) after `Foo` declaration:

```
template<typename R>
struct Foo {
    R ref;
    int info;
};

template<typename R> Foo(R, int) -> Foo<R>;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/q8KE75s9Y)

Comment: It's not needed past C++20. An aggregate deduction guide is created automatically.